Route encoding Angular 12: Routing not working as expected
Recently upgraded Angular application from version 9 to 12.
Now, my current routes are not working, and encoded to %23.
Here is an example of my routes:
{ path: 'app-terminal-request-list', component: AppTerminalRequestListComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: { viewDescription: eAppFunction.AppTerminalList } }

Here is how I route to it, using routerLink:
<li [hasAccess]="HasAccessAppTerminalListing">
    <a routerLink="/app-terminal-request-list" routerLinkActive="active">
        <span class="link-text">Terminal Request History</span>
    </a>
</li>

When I click on the <li> in my nav-bar, it tries to navigate to:
http://localhost:4200/%23

I am not sure why the routing now behaves differently in Angular 12.

%23 is # so maybe something with your hash routing setup is wrong. Can you set a minimal reproduction?

Yeah, thats correct @JSONDerulo he should just add  { useHash: false } in the routing config and that will solve it

Some things you should check:
In your index.html, check if there is something like that inside your  tag:
<base href="/">

If not, add it.
Then, check your routing file. It should have something like this:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }


If none of that works, try changing your  to something like this:
<a [routerLink]="['app-terminal-request-list']" routerLinkActive="active">


It is very likely that the / in your path is being enconded for some reason.

I do have { useHash: false } set...
This seems to only happen to expandable menu items in the nav.
Changing routerLink to href seems to solve the issue

Yeah but href isnt supposed to be used in angular...
